# Showing mixed partial derivatives of this function are not the same

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am looking at the following problem in advanced calculus by Fitzpatrick.

> Show that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
> 0,&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
> has second order partial derivatives but $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x}(0,0)=-1$ while $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)=1$. First show $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)=x$ then show $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,y)=-y$.

I am just confused here because if I start the problem by calculating $$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t}=0$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(0,t)-f(0,0)}{t}=0,$$ it would seem to me the second order partials should both be $0$. What is wrong with using this approach, and why must I follow the book's suggestion to compute the partial derivatives, and get a different result?

Comment: You are only finding the first partials at $(0,0)$, but the hint is telling you to calculate its values on an entire line i.e. by definition $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0) = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,0)}{y-0}$$

Comment: Maybe thinking about the one-dimensional case will help clarify things.  Consider $f(x) = x^2$.  Then $f'(0) = 0$ but $f''(0) = 2$.  Knowing the value of $f'(0)$ doesn't tell you anything about the value of $f''(0)$.